# Ошибка: aiogram.exceptions.TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: user not found

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import Message
import asyncio
from telegram import ParseMode
from aiogram import types

# Устанавливаем уровень логгирования
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Создаем объект диспетчера
dp = Dispatcher()
bot = Bot("")

@dp.message()
async def check_subscription(message: Message):
    if not message.chat.type == 'group' or not message.chat.type == 'supergroup':
        user_channel_status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id='@tesnfkromr', user_id=message.from_user.id)
        print(user_id)
        user_channel_status = re.findall(r"\w*", str(user_channel_status))
        try:
            if user_channel_status[70] == 'left':
                await message.delete()
                await message.answer("Вы не можете писать в этой группе, пока не подпишетесь на все необходимые каналы.") 
                #Условие для тех, кто не подписан
        except:
            if user_channel_status[60] == 'left':
                await message.delete()
                await message.answer("Вы не можете писать в этой группе, пока не подпишетесь на все необходимые каналы.") 
                #Условие для тех, кто не подписан

async def main() -> None:
    # Initialize Bot instance with a default parse mode which will be passed to all API calls
    bot = Bot("", parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML) 
    # And the run events dispatching
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


# Запуск бота
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

При отправке сообщения в группу вылезает ошибка aiogram.exceptions.TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: user not found. Я так понимаю, что сервер не читает данные пользователя, вопрос почему?

Answer (score 0):

Это происходит из-за того, что вы удаляете сообщения с помощью `await message.delete()`, а потом пытаетесь ответить на них с помощью `await message.answer()`. Используйте вместо этого функцию `await bot.send_message()`, которая не будет ссылаться на удалённое сообщение.

Comment: к сожалению, не помогло

Comment: Та же ошибка?..

Comment: да( я проверил, там она проявляется ещё до момента отправки и удаления сообщений. я думаю ещё при user_channel_status

Comment: хотя id выводит